# using one application for design and milling wood project with CNC

Tags: milling, cnc

Here is the full scenario for any project, have failure every time :

- design 3D model with sketchup
- measure the size and try to convert it into 2D shapes with some vector applicatins ( like Adobe Illustrator )
- import the vector into Vectric Aspire
- nest shapes into the sheet
- re-check then plan several times
- set the right tool-path and cut the material
- **problem with sizing every time specially on dado cuts and joints**

I think the problem is switching between these applications , so the human errors is unavoidable.

The question is : are there any applications for doing all these steps with one software .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that you are agreeable to learning new software. One product pops into my alleged mind when you ask for a "do it all" type of program.

Fusion 360 is free for students, hobbyists and for business that produce below a certain level of income (or is it profit) using the software. For the DIY fellows and gals and hobbyists, it is required to renew the license yearly, a minor task.

F360 is capable of creating 3D models, perhaps not as easily as SketchUp but reasonably easy to learn. Dimensioning is a feature incorporated into Fusion 360 as well as parametric modeling.

Another aspect of F360 is that it is a fully functional CAD/CAM package and you would be able to generate your tool paths directly from your work/models.

There are many resources for learning Fusion 360. Lynda.com provides tutorials and YouTube is loaded with instructional videos.

Our local library has a license agreement with Lynda.com to allow patrons access to their resources at no cost.

I've viewed for entertainment purposes a number of YouTube creators who use Fusion 360 to generate tool paths for their CNC wood router with good results.

Comment: I think this is a good approach to reduce the number of application hops.